# Is mediterranean climate a type of monsoon climate

Tags: geography, climatology, monsoon, mediterranean

Given that monsoon climate has the primary feature of seasonal reversal of wind systems and the same happens in case of Mediterranean climate too, does that mean Mediterranean climate is a special case of Monsoon?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-right-to-say-that-the-mediterranean-climate-is-a-type-of-monsoon-climate :)

Comment: The Quora answer says- Mediterranean climate isn’t a seasonal reversal of winds per se but a overlap of two different wind systems across the same region. But the same happens in Indian Monsoon where the subcontinent comes under NE Trades in winter and SW Monsoon in summer due to seasonal migration of Sun- the same reason that causes Mediterranean region to come under 2 wind systems.

Comment: one is due to movement of ITCZ and the other differences are monsoon is primarily a low level phenomenon i.e. convergence etc...but the other one is upper level (500 hPa and above)

Comment: Please elaborate because even ITCZ movement is due to seasonal migration of Sun.

Comment: Indian monsoon is due to dynamics of ITCZ. Mediterranean rainfall is due to mid latitude dynamics - baroclinicity etc Check out my answer on Indian monsoon